# how to send apns notification with a picture in it

Tags: iphone, image, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

how to send apns notification with a picture in it as fellow:

[image]

should I put the image file name in the customer field or anything else?

Comment: It is not a picture but an emoji character.

Comment: I think it should be a build-in picture, so actually it should be some characters like "/heart" etc.

Comment: do you know which emoji character will be shown as a "red heart"?

Comment: In which language you use to send notification like java php ..etc

Comment: @user1556497 The "red heart" emoji you are looking for is ❤